# Python: scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh for complex Hermitian matrices

Tags: python, scipy, complex-numbers, eigenvalue

I am trying to diagonalise a simple sparse Hermitian matrix using python's scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh function; although [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh) says it supports Hermitian matrices, the file python wrapper file arpack.py says it does not:

> # The entry points to ARPACK are
>
> # - (s,d)seupd : single and double precision symmetric matrix
>
> # - (s,d,c,z)neupd: single,double,complex,double complex general matrix
>
> # This wrapper puts the *neupd (general matrix) interfaces in eigs()
>
> # and the *seupd (symmetric matrix) in eigsh().
>
> # There is no Hermetian complex/double complex interface.
>
> # **To find eigenvalues of a Hermetian matrix you**
>
> # **must use eigs() and not eigsh()**
>
> # It might be desirable to handle the Hermetian case differently
>
> # and, for example, return real eigenvalues.

Indeed the above comments from the wrapper are vindicated when I try to run the following code for diagonalising a sparse complex Hermitian matrix using eigsh:

```
from scipy.sparse import *
from scipy.sparse.linalg import *
import math

sign = lambda x: math.copysign(1, x)

S = lil_matrix((5,5), dtype=complex)
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        S[i,j] = sign(i-j)*1j

eigval = eigsh(-S, k=1, M=None,sigma=None, which='LM', v0=None, ncv=None, tol=0, return_eigenvectors=False)
```

Then the following error comes up:

> ValueError: Input matrix is not real-valued.

Of course, if I use a regular numpy matrix for S and the numpy.linalg.eigh function, then all the eigenvalues are computed. But

- I do not want all the eigenvalues, and
- I need my matrix to be sparse.

Does anyone know what then is the point of having a sparse version eigsh for sparse complex Hermitian matrices if it cannot be used?

*Note*: I understand that the matrix in the example here is not necessarily sparse by some definition of sparsity but it's just used for illustrative purposes.

Comment: `eigsh` can be used by first converting the complex _n X n_ matrix to a _2n X 2n_ real matrix: `S2n = hstack((vstack((S.real,-S.imag)), vstack((S.imag,S.real)))).real` and then using `eigh` on **S2n**.